# How to consume a WSDL from a BPEL process with Java?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, bpel

I need to make a Java webservice that sends XML to a BPEL process and receives a return message.

I have the WSDL from the BPEL process:

```
<definitions name="SJATR"
             targetNamespace="http://www.oracle.com/retail/xpto/integration/SJATR"
             xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
             xmlns:client="http://www.oracle.com/retail/xpto/integration/SJATR"
             xmlns:plnk="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/05/partner-link/">
   <types>
      <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
         <import namespace="http://www.oracle.com/retail/xpto/integration/SJATR"
                    xmlns="http://www.oracle.com/retail/xpto/integration/SJATR"
                    xmlns:lmx="http://www.oracle.com/retail/xpto/integration/lmxbrasn"
                    schemaLocation="SJATR.xsd"/> 
      </schema>                    
   </types>                    
   <message name="SJATRReqMsg">
      <part name="payload" element="client:SJATRReq"/>
   </message>
   <message name="SJATRRespMsg">
      <part name="payload" element="client:SJATRResp"/>
   </message>
   <portType name="SJATR">
      <operation name="initiate">
         <input message="client:SJATRReqMsg"/>
         <output message="client:SJATRRespMsg"/>
      </operation>
   </portType>      
   <plnk:partnerLinkType name="SJATR">
      <plnk:role name="SJATRProvider">
         <plnk:portType name="client:SJATR"/>
      </plnk:role>     
   </plnk:partnerLinkType>
</definitions>
```

Now I need to make the jax-ws to invoke that WSDL file from the BPEL.
What should I do? Should I use `wsimport` to create the stubs? If so, then what?

Comment: If the WSDL is available, I would have `wsimport` generate all the class files you need. Then using the Service (a little tricky) you can call the web service

Comment: @Ascalonian can you explain to me the Service part? I guess that's what I'm missing.

Comment: After generating all the code, there will be a class that ends with `Service`.  Create an instance of that, then call a method that ends with `PortTypeSoap` to get the portType. After that, there should be a method on the port that matches the name of the service you're trying to call. You should be able to go from there. Keep in mind, I did this with wsimport from Java 7

Comment: Except there is no service element...